# How do you resolve an error when trying to initiate a phone call on iOS, com.apple.telephonyutilities.callservicesdaemon.callstatecontroller

Tags: ios, swift, telephony

I create a phone `URL` with:

```
let phoneLink = "tel://5551119999"
if let url = URL(string: phoneLink) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url) {
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to resolve:

> Error using remote object proxy: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain
>   Code=4099 "The connection to service named
>   com.apple.telephonyutilities.callservicesdaemon.callstatecontroller
>   was invalidated."

I have attempted several different formats for the phone `string`, `URL(string: )` seems pretty lenient and will accept different types of `strings` and convert them correctly, so I don't think that's the issue.

I have added logs so I know my code is only being run once so it isn't an issue of making several calls to `UIApplication.shared.open()`

Comment: No, that's not the real number I am using.

Comment: Remove the //. Does the number you are trying to call contain characters # or * ?